Why would an ios app work with App Group (Shared Folder) in DEBUG mode, but not in RELEASE mode? Have I lost my entitlements.plist in release?
I have successfully implemented App Group shared folder in 3 apps now.  One of these is almost identical to the app I am working with now.  These are Xamarin.Forms apps, and I am using Visual Studio.
And from Visual Studio, I "debug" the app in question (or, run after debug deployment), and the shared folder works fine.  But building in "release" mode and sending to TestFlight, the App Group folder does not seem to exist.
Here is my code:
try {
    savedLog += $"Util[iOS].ctor - Atttempt to get Group folder" + "\r\n";
    var FileManager = new NSFileManager();
    savedLog += $"Util[iOS].ctor - FileManager={FileManager}" + "\r\n";
    var appGroupContainer =
        FileManager.GetContainerUrl("group.com.pronktech.mobilize");
    savedLog += $"Util[iOS].ctor - appGroupContainer={appGroupContainer}" + "\r\n";
    groupFolderPath = appGroupContainer.Path;
    savedLog += $"Util[iOS].ctor - groupFolderPath={groupFolderPath}" + "\r\n";
} catch (Exception ex) {
    savedLog += $"Util[iOS].ctor - Exception on getting groupFolderPath, ex={ex.Message}" + "\r\n";
}

Here is the "savedLog" after:
Util[iOS].ctor - Atttempt to get Group folder\r\n
Util[iOS].ctor - FileManager=<NSFileManager: 0x3015b7e60>\r\n
Util[iOS].ctor - appGroupContainer=\r\n
Util[iOS].ctor - Exception on getting groupFolderPath, ex=Object reference not set to an instance of an object\r\n

So, it appears that FileManager.GetContainerURL() is returning an empty string.
UPDATE:  after writing, before posting, a theory has formed:  Could the entitlements.plist file NOT be getting applied in Release mode?  In looking at the differences in Metadata on appstoreconnect.com, it's clear that there are unexplained differences in Metadata, including no

"com.apple.security.application-groups: ( "group.com.mycompany.myapp"
)"

For reference, the entitlements.plist file is exactly the same in both apps (other than the reference to its identifier in keychain-access-groups).

Check the XCode build settings and confirm what the Code Signing Entitlements file is set to, and if release differs from debug

@Piepants.  Yes, that is exactly the problem...  I don't understand why this is on the signing page, but either never got set, or somehow got cleared.

This was total cockpit error -- just like @piepants said, on the Build settings, under "iOS Bundle Signing" the "Custom Entitlements" entry was cleared.  Browsed to "Entitlements.plist", now the metadata matches the other apps in this regard.
I'm still a little mystified -- I had a couple other "entitlements", like for wireless accessory configuration, but it didn't seem to cause a problem not having this.
